# return instance of interface without declaring a variable without casting

Tags: typescript

In typescript, you can define an interface and create an instance of it by declaring a variable of that interface type and setting the properties appropriately like this.

```
interface Thing{
  id: number,
  name: string
}

const thing: Thing = {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
}
```

However, if I have a method or function that returns that interface type I cannot figure out how to return an instance of it without first creating a variable to return.

So I can do this:

```
function getThing(): Thing {
  const thing: Thing = {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
  }
  return thing;
}
```

I can't figure out, what if any, is the correct syntax to do this

```
function getThing(): Thing {  
  return: Thing = {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
  }
}
```

I know I can do this:

```
function getThing(): Thing {  
  return <Thing> {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
  };
}
```

But that removes some amount of type checking that I would rather remain.

Is it possible to return an instance of an interface without declaring a variable and without casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either return the instance directly

```
function getThing(): Thing {  
  return {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
  };
}
```

Or to specify explicitly that the instance is of type `Thing` via `as` operator:

```
function getThing(): Thing {  
  return {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
  } as Thing;
}
```

Note that in the 2nd example, adding the `as Thing` part is un-necessary

Comment: I had thought I tried that and it didn't work but I must have made some other mistake because now I have just amended my actual code and it works fine.

Comment: I would avoid the “as”.  You are actually weakening the type checking when you include that.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks I figured that was probably the case.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Of course, there is no need to add `as` here. That was just an additional note ;)

Comment: This answer is not enforcing the property checks, you can add a property in the returned object that does not exist in the interface. The solution should show an error if returning an object with extra properties that are not in the declared interface

Answer (score 3):

Just directly return it, Typescript will know that the thing you're returning should in fact be a Thing:

```
interface Thing{
  id: number,
  name: string
}

function getThing(): Thing {  
  return {
    id:1,
    name:'my thing'
  }
}
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMDeAoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoAaAiuaicgZzCmzwF88eGJRAIwwAPYhkWCGAzYAFAEpyCkFmQ5CzKHMpRp%20QoRKkAjExMs2pAOTUAnsjCYNd5gL5A).

Comment: Typescript knows but the IDE (for example VSCode) will not complain if you add a property to the return object that does not exist in the interface. While declaring a variable of type `Thing` and initializing it that way, it will show an error if you try to add a property that is not defined in the interface.

Comment: @Johnny In my experience, the above is caught by both the compiler and IDE. For example, see the playground link in my post. Perhaps your IDE has a more lenient config? Specific tsconfig settings perhaps?

Comment: you are right, this seems to be a VSCode issue. I was not able to find why VSCode is not reporting this as an error. Thanks anyway.